Running Legacy ASP.net Code: Seeking Guidance for Visual Studio 2008
How can I decipher the purpose and functionality of a legacy ASP.net project developed in Visual Studio 2008, given its age and potential lack of documentation? Could you guide me through the process? thanks
I installed Visual Studio 2022 but it seems doesn't work with the legacy projects

At a minimum, you can read the code in VS 2022. VS is a text editor at its core, and you can open the legacy app's .vb/.html files.
